# Getting PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException When running docker app using springboot and aws

Tags: spring, docker, spring-cloud-aws

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.